# Execute Python Script on a pre-loaded PowerBI dataset

Tags: python, powerbi

This is possibly a very simple ask.
I have imported an excel dataset into PowerBI which is named as "dataset".

What I want to do now is execute some python script within the query editor on this dataset but I'm not sure how I reference it?

For example, If I want to simply add a column my code would look like
dataset['New Column'] = "New Row information"

But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

First, import and load the required dataset in powerbi desktop.we can also create visualization graphs and plots using python script.
in visualizations tab, select python visual(PY) and select required fields from the dataset. a python script editor will be displayed.
for example, adding a new column in the dataset:
dataset['New']=&Text.From(param1)&" ",[dataset=#"Changed Type"])